# Callback during sign- in process in order to change boolean to true or false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using the devise gem with my app. Which callback should I use in order to pass a method from my user model during the sign in process??

`Warden::Manager.after_set_user ?
before_validation?
before_save?
before_create?`

Method details: 
I have a boolean column:is_active in the users table.
Each time a user tries to sign in, the braintree code finds if the user has has an active or not subscription thru the braintree api. And if the user has and active or not subscription I'm trying to update the is_active column to true or false.

I'm using this currently, but it's not working:

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user :scope => :user do |user, auth, opts|

  customer = Braintree::Customer.find('customer_id')
  customer_card = customer.payment_methods[0].token
  payment_method = Braintree::PaymentMethod.find(customer_card)
  sub = payment_method.subscriptions[0]
  sub.status

if Braintree::Subscription::Status::Active
  obj = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  obj.is_active = true
  obj.save!

else
  obj = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  obj.is_active = false
  obj.save!
 end
end

def active_for_authentication?
  super && is_active?
end

def inactive_message
  "User not active, please subscribe!"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Braintree::Subscription::Status::Active` is merely a [constant pointing to a string](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ruby/blob/02db6f8d75830aa3338d61985183aab4eebfab9b/lib/braintree/subscription.rb#L13) `"Active"`, it's always "truthy". That means that `if Braintree::Subscription::Status::Active` will always be true.

You probably want to do this instead:

```
user.update(is_active: sub.status == Braintree::Subscription::Status::Active)
```

No need for that conditional or explicitly setting `true` or `false` based on the condition of the block, and you already have a `User` instance passed to the block so you don't need to load one from the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @coreyward! Also another question I have is, should I use another callback other then `Warden::Manager.after_set_user` ?